# ActionScript 3; Easing with Different Velocity?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, physics, tween, easing

Although I've worked with C# for a while, I've recently switched gears to attempt a project in ActionScript 3 on Adobe Flash CS4. This is my first real attempt at code in Flash. What I'm trying to do is essentially fake the physics of a rocket. What I'm making is a scrolling shooter, and I'm using tweens to move a rocketship from left to right with easing.

My problem is dynamic easing. I have it set up so when you press either the Left or Right arrow key (I'll continue to make an example of pressing Left), a Tween moves the ship to the corresponding direction with Regular.easeIn until you let go of the key. Then it uses another tween with Regular.easeOut to slow you down. But lets say that you let go of the Left key, and then press it again. It immediately cancels your velocity to ease you in to another tween. I don't want this. Is there any way to make a tween or engineer one so that it doesn't start with zero velocity (with ActionScript, of course)?

Comment: Let's see the code you've got set up

Comment: Do you have a specific question?I mean I do not undestand what you want, reduce this to the actual problem

Comment: Which Tween class are you using?  The better ones will start a property from where it is already (and kill other tweens in progress).  Also, modelling actual physics equations may be easier than messing with tweens for this...